# setState() in React not updating state onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am building a component that renders data from a Redux store grouped by week. Since the week is only relevant to this component, I am storing its value as a local state as follows:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      page: 0,
      week: this.getWeekNumber(new Date())[1],
      year: this.getWeekNumber(new Date())[0]
    };
  }
```

This is normally what I do in my components and never had any issues with this approach. I have three buttons that will re-render the data based on the week:

```
...
render() {
...
       <Button onClick={() => this.handleRenderWeek("previous")}>
          Previous Week
        </Button>
        <Button onClick={() => this.handleRenderWeek("current")}>
          Current Week
        </Button>
        <Button onClick={() => this.handleRenderWeek("next")}>Next Week</Button>
...
```

The helper function that handles the render is defined as follows:

```
  handleRenderWeek = action => {
    const { week, year, page } = this.state;
    switch (action) {
      case "previous":
        this.setState({
          page: 0,
          week: week - 1,
          year
        });
        break;
      case "current":
        this.setState({
          page: 0,
          week: this.getWeekNumber(new Date())[1],
          year: this.getWeekNumber(new Date())[0]
        });
        break;
      case "next":
        this.setState(prevState => ({ week: prevState.week + 1 }));
        break;
      default:
        this.setState({
          page: 0,
          week: this.getWeekNumber(new Date())[1],
          year: this.getWeekNumber(new Date())[0]
        });
        break;
    }
    this.props.fetchCalendarsAndBookings(week, year, page);
  };
```

The problem is that when I click the `next week` button, the `week` state remains the same. It only increments when I do a second click. When I again the third, fourth, etc time, it continues to increment correctly.

When I click on the `current week` and `previous week` buttons, following the above, I experience the exact same thing: first click the state remains the same (hence sending an API call with the previous state), and then it starts working on the second click onwards.

After some research I found out that `setState()` is called asynchronously, so I replaced the above code to have `setState()` referring to its previous state as follows:

```
this.setState((prevState, props) => {
            return {
              week: prevState.week + 1
            };
          });
```

However this did not fix the issue, and I am still having the same problem. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I recall vaguely this has something to do with the click event being marked as handled, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Is initial state `week` prop is correct?

Comment: Is `handleRenderWeek` declared _before_ or _after_ `render()`?

Comment: @IvanBurnaev what do you mean?

Comment: @DJ. didn't make a difference which place is declared

Comment: @JamesJ.does `this.getWeekNumber(new Date())[1]` return a number? Can you show what `this.state` looks like in constructor? `console.log(this.state)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after hours of investigation I managed to find the root cause of the problem. Apparently what was happening is that `setState()` was updating the `week` state late. The API was being called with the older version of the state.

To solve the issue, I made use of the `async/await`:

1. First update the state and `await`
2. Then call the API to fetch the results.

The code now looks something like this:

```
  handleRenderWeek = async action => {
    switch (action) {
      case "previous":
        await this.decrementWeek();
        break;
      case "current":
        await this.resetWeek();
        break;
      case "next":
        await this.incrementWeek();
        break;
      default:
        await this.resetWeek();
        break;
    }
    console.log("Updated State: ", this.state.week);
    await this.props.fetchCalendarsAndBookings(
      this.state.week,
      this.state.year,
      this.state.page
    );
  };
```

The cardinal lessons here are two:

1. `setState()` is an asynchronous function. Big woo.
2. When mixing `setState()` with redux thunks and other complex async functions, always chain them accordingly with `then()`, or even simpler, using the `async/await` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The next button in the snippet below works as expected. Other buttons fail due to undefined procedures. I kept this as close to your code as possible. I do not think your problems is contained in the code you provide in your question.

```js
class Hello extends React.Component {

 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
    this.state = {
     week: 0
    };
  }
  
  handleRenderWeek(action) {
    const { week, year, page } = this.state;
    switch (action) {
      case "previous":
        this.setState({
          page: 0,
          week: week - 1,
          year
        });
        break;
      case "current":
        this.setState({
          page: 0,
          week: this.getWeekNumber(new Date())[1],
          year: this.getWeekNumber(new Date())[0]
        });
        break;
      case "next":
        this.setState(prevState => ({ week: prevState.week + 1 }));
        break;
      default:
        this.setState({
          page: 0,
          week: this.getWeekNumber(new Date())[1],
          year: this.getWeekNumber(new Date())[0]
        });
        break;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
     <div>
        <div>Hello {this.props.name}, week is {this.state.week}</div>
        <button onClick={() => this.handleRenderWeek("previous")}>
          Previous Week
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => this.handleRenderWeek("current")}>
          Current Week
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => this.handleRenderWeek("next")}>Next Week</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```